# programmatically add a button to list view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I want add a button to some of the rows in the list view under particular condition . Can some one suggest any method to implement the same ?

Comment: What condition and when ?

Comment: Are you using custom adapter for your ListView?

Answer (score 1):

you have to implement custom listview for this so you need custom adapter. and in custom adapter's getview methods, grab the current view i.e convertview parameter and then create a button programmatically and add that button to the listview item under conditions that you want to set.